# match regex doesn't return matched group

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse a git diff string to get all updated npm packages.

This is my regex `new RegExp(/^\+\s{4}\"(.*)\":\s\"(.*)\"/gm)` using with this example string:

```
index ab40f85..dc6d42f 100755
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -1,7 +1,6 @@
{
"name": "name",
"version": "0.0.0",
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
@@ -79,7 +78,7 @@
    "next": "12.0.4",
    "next-auth": "^3.29.0",
    "next-with-apollo": "^5.2.1",
-    "passport": "^0.5.0",
+    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pdfkit": "^0.13.0",
@@ -113,18 +112,18 @@
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "^3.2.1",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.0",
-    "@nrwl/cli": "13.2.3",
-    "@nrwl/cypress": "13.2.3",
-    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "13.2.3",
-    "@nrwl/jest": "13.2.3",
-    "@nrwl/linter": "13.2.3",
-    "@nrwl/nest": "13.2.3",
-    "@nrwl/next": "13.2.3",
-    "@nrwl/node": "13.2.3",
-    "@nrwl/react": "13.2.3",
-    "@nrwl/tao": "13.2.3",
-    "@nrwl/web": "13.2.3",
-    "@nrwl/workspace": "13.2.3",
+    "@nrwl/cli": "13.2.4",
+    "@nrwl/cypress": "13.2.4",
+    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "13.2.4",
+    "@nrwl/jest": "13.2.4",
+    "@nrwl/linter": "13.2.4",
+    "@nrwl/nest": "13.2.4",
+    "@nrwl/next": "13.2.4",
+    "@nrwl/node": "13.2.4",
+    "@nrwl/react": "13.2.4",
+    "@nrwl/tao": "13.2.4",
+    "@nrwl/web": "13.2.4",
+    "@nrwl/workspace": "13.2.4",
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^8.0.1",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^8.11.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.0",
```

With the regex I should get all packages starting with an `+` and the groups should have the name and the version.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wMHyEE/1)

But running

```
const updated = diff.match(regex)
console.log(updated)
```

gives me

```
[
    '+    "passport": "^0.4.0"',
    '+    "@nrwl/cli": "13.2.4"',
    '+    "@nrwl/cypress": "13.2.4"',
    '+    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "13.2.4"',
    '+    "@nrwl/jest": "13.2.4"',
    '+    "@nrwl/linter": "13.2.4"',
    '+    "@nrwl/nest": "13.2.4"',
    '+    "@nrwl/next": "13.2.4"',
    '+    "@nrwl/node": "13.2.4"',
    '+    "@nrwl/react": "13.2.4"',
    '+    "@nrwl/tao": "13.2.4"',
    '+    "@nrwl/web": "13.2.4"',
    '+    "@nrwl/workspace": "13.2.4"'
]
```

I'm missing the group results. And I would expect only the names and the versions (without spaces, `"` and `:`) and I need both for further processing.

Comment: [String.prototype.matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll), but maybe you rather want `exec` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

As it was mentioned in the comments, the best solution would be to use the RegExp function `exec` ([mdn documenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)) to get the groups, for each match. you would have to loop until no, result is found.

Here a small demo *(with the provided data and expression)*:

```js
let expression = new RegExp(/^\+\s{4}\"(.*)\":\s\"(.*)\"/gm)
let data = `index ab40f85..dc6d42f 100755
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -1,7 +1,6 @@
{
"name": "name",
"version": "0.0.0",
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
@@ -79,7 +78,7 @@
    "next": "12.0.4",
    "next-auth": "^3.29.0",
    "next-with-apollo": "^5.2.1",
-    "passport": "^0.5.0",
+    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pdfkit": "^0.13.0",
@@ -113,18 +112,18 @@
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "^3.2.1",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.0",
-    "@nrwl/cli": "13.2.3",
-    "@nrwl/cypress": "13.2.3",
-    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "13.2.3",
-    "@nrwl/jest": "13.2.3",
-    "@nrwl/linter": "13.2.3",
-    "@nrwl/nest": "13.2.3",
-    "@nrwl/next": "13.2.3",
-    "@nrwl/node": "13.2.3",
-    "@nrwl/react": "13.2.3",
-    "@nrwl/tao": "13.2.3",
-    "@nrwl/web": "13.2.3",
-    "@nrwl/workspace": "13.2.3",
+    "@nrwl/cli": "13.2.4",
+    "@nrwl/cypress": "13.2.4",
+    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "13.2.4",
+    "@nrwl/jest": "13.2.4",
+    "@nrwl/linter": "13.2.4",
+    "@nrwl/nest": "13.2.4",
+    "@nrwl/next": "13.2.4",
+    "@nrwl/node": "13.2.4",
+    "@nrwl/react": "13.2.4",
+    "@nrwl/tao": "13.2.4",
+    "@nrwl/web": "13.2.4",
+    "@nrwl/workspace": "13.2.4",
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^8.0.1",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^8.11.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.0",`
   
   let match;
   let result = []
   while (match = expression.exec(data)){
    result.push(match);
   }
   
   console.info(result)
```

***Disclaimer:** apart from a demo, I would not use the assignment in the while loop condition. you could use the `lastIndex` property of the expression, or so.*